# Как реализовать прозрачность вокруг указателя?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Коллеги подскажите на JS(или на чистом css возможно) при помощи чего можно реализовать подобное решение 
https://www.kikk.be/2018/en/home
Прозрачность области, при наведении мыши, определенного радиуса.
Пройдите по ссылке поводите мышкой, чтоб понять о чем я.
Благодарен заранее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по вышеприведенной ссылке все нарисовано на канве. и это не прозрачность

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По вышеприведенной ссылке все нарисовано на канве. И это не прозрачность.

Нечто подобное можно сделать с `svg` + `mask` или `clip-path`

Верхнее изображение размыто блюром и из него вырезаны круги, а нижнее такое же как верхнее только без блюра и вырезанных кругов.

Таскайте мышкой за круги

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let d = [[100,100,70], [300,100,60], [500,100,50]]
         .map(d=>({x: d[0], y: d[1], r: d[2]}));
let mask = circles('mask').call(upd);
  
circles('g').style('fill','transparent')
  .style('cursor','pointer')
  .call(upd)
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function (d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
    mask.call(upd)  
  }));

function circles(selector) {
  return d3.select(selector)
           .selectAll('circle')
           .data(d)
           .enter()
           .append('circle')
}

function upd(selection) {
   selection.attr("cx", d => d.x)
            .attr("cy", d => d.y)
            .attr('r',  d => d.r);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600">
<defs>
  <filter id="blurfilter" width="110%" height="100%">
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12" result="blur" />
  </filter>
  <mask id="hole">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
  </mask>
</defs>
<image x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="200%"
       xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png"/>
<image mask="url(#hole)" filter="url(#blurfilter)"
       x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="200%"
       xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png" />
<g></g>
</svg>
```

PS: если же хочется получить эффекты побогаче придется обратиться на темную сторону (WebGL)

Comment: так то это круто смотрится за что + и слепил но там не хватает одной плюшки ..

Comment: @MaximLensky эффект то вокруг круга?

Comment: да...я даже не знаю как это называется ..типа зернистость что ли ...х.з

Comment: @MaximLensky это уже на webgl надо монстрячить, может вечером посмотрю на это поближе